# Reduce the scope of a javascript library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

In my Angular app, I made a component that can show a very specific format of images and that need an external js library, which I import in `<head>`.

The problem is, that js lib uses jQuery and messes with my html with very unwise jQuery selectors that match my own code.

Is there a way to limit the scope of that library ?

Comment: That's not the way to use libraries in Angular. What's the name of the library ? Can't you use another one ?

Comment: @temp_user I absolutely can't use another library, trust me it's a very specific tool.

Comment: Well then trust me you're f*cked. Either rewrite this library or your own components so that they don't clash, or change library.